# Deploy app to heroku using terraform in Gitlab CI/CD

Tags: python, heroku, terraform, gitlab-ci

I have a problem with deploying my Django app on Heroku using Terraform.  An application can be found in a public repository here: https://gitlab.com/Draqun/pa-forum
Locally when I use terraform init and terraform apply all works fine. Sadly these same steps ran in CICD fail.

> Error: Provider produced inconsistent final plan
>
> When expanding the plan for heroku_build.pa_forum_build to include new
> values learned so far during apply, provider
> "registry.terraform.io/heroku/heroku" produced an invalid new value
> for .local_checksum: was
> cty.StringVal("SHA256:87bc408ce0cd8e1466c2d836cdfe2564b06d7ac8defd946c103b05918994ce49"),
> but now
> cty.StringVal("SHA256:dd8a0aaf8adc091ef32bf06cae1bd645dbbd8f549f692a4ba4d1c385ed94fc6b").
>
> This is a bug in the provider, which should be reported in the
> provider's own issue tracker.

I had these error before when application source code was directly in root directory. I moved code from root directory into src directory and it resolved problems with deploy app from local machine. Sadly it does not helped with CICD deploy.

My CICD configuration looks like that:

```yaml
image: python:3.9-slim-buster

variables:
  PYTHONPATH: src/
  TF_PLAN: app.tfplan
  TF_STATE: app.tf_state
  TF_VAR_source_version: $CI_COMMIT_SHA

cache:
  key: "project-${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}"
  paths:
    - .cache/pip
    - .venv
    - src/requirements.txt

before_script:
  - python -V  # Print out python version for debugging
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get upgrade -y
  - apt-get install -y make gettext
  - pip install --upgrade pip
  - pip install virtualenv poetry
  - poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true
  - poetry install --remove-untracked
  - make init-env
  - make create-env
  - make freeze
  - source .venv/bin/activate

stages:
  - build
  - tests
  - deploy-plan
  - deploy
  - cleanup
  - pages
  - destroy

.tf-job:
  image:
    name: hashicorp/terraform:1.0.6
    entrypoint: [""]
  before_script:
    - cd terraform/
    - terraform --version
    - terraform providers
    - terraform init
    - terraform fmt
    - terraform validate

.tf-destroy:
  extends: .tf-job
  dependencies:
    - tf-apply-job
  script:
    - terraform destroy -state=$TF_STATE -auto-approve

generate-messages-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - python3 src/manage.py makemessages -l pl
    - python3 src/manage.py compilemessages -l pl
  cache:
    paths:
      - src/locale/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - src/locale/

tests-job:
  services:
    - postgres:12.2-alpine
  stage: tests
  variables:
    POSTGRES_DB: custom_db
    POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
    POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
    POSTGRES_USER: custom_user
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: custom_pass
    POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
    DATABASE_URL: postgres://$POSTGRES_USER:$POSTGRES_PASSWORD@postgres:5432/$POSTGRES_DB
  script:
    - python3 src/manage.py migrate
    - .cicd/scripts/run_tests.sh src/manage.py
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - report/

static-analysis-job:
  stage: tests
  script:
    - .cicd/scripts/static_analysis.sh src/forum/

tf-plan-job:
  extends: .tf-job
  stage: deploy-plan
  script:
    - terraform plan -state=$TF_STATE -out=$TF_PLAN
  cache:
    paths:
      - terraform/.terraform.lock.hcl
      - terraform/.terraform
      - terraform/$TF_STATE
      - terraform/$TF_PLAN
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - terraform/$TF_STATE
      - terraform/$TF_PLAN
    expire_in: 7 days

tf-apply-job:
  extends: .tf-job
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ls -al .
    - ls -al ../src/
    - ls -al ../src/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES
    - terraform apply -auto-approve -state=$TF_STATE $TF_PLAN
  after_script:
    - terraform show
  dependencies:
    - tf-plan-job
  only:
    - master

cleanup-job:
  extends: .tf-destroy
  stage: cleanup
  when: on_failure

pages:
  stage: pages
  script:
    - mkdir doc
    - cd doc; make html
    - mv _build/html/ ../public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  when: manual
  only:
    - master

tf-destroy-job:
  extends: .tf-destroy
  stage: destroy
  when: manual
```

main.tf looks like that

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    heroku = {
      source  = "heroku/heroku"
      version = "~> 4.6.0"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 0.14"
}

resource "heroku_app" "pa_forum" {
  name   = "python-academy-forum-${var.environment}"
  region = "eu"

  config_vars = {
    LOG_LEVEL = "info"
    DEBUG     = false
    VERSION   = var.source_version
  }
}

resource "heroku_addon" "postgres" {
  app  = heroku_app.pa_forum.id
  plan = "heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev"
}

resource "heroku_build" "pa_forum_build" {
  app = heroku_app.pa_forum.id

  source {
    path    = var.source_dir
    version = var.source_version
  }
}

resource "heroku_config" "common" {
  sensitive_vars = {
    SECRET_KEY = "1234%^&*()someRandomData)(*&^%$#@!"
  }
}

resource "heroku_formation" "pa_forum_formation" {
  app        = heroku_app.pa_forum.id
  quantity   = var.app_quantity
  size       = "Free"
  type       = "web"
  depends_on = [heroku_build.pa_forum_build]
}
```

I need solution for a problem with failing deploy.
Also any proposition to improve CI/CD process or Terraform scripts are also welcome.

Any help will be appreciated.
Best regards.
Draqun